Usage of SparkMetric_CL, SparkListenerEvent_CL and SparkLoggingEvent_CL
I am wondering If can retrieve any information from Azure Log Analytics custom tables (already set) for Azure Databricks. Would like to retrieve information about query and data performance for SQL Warehouse Cluster. I am not sure If I can get it from custom log analytics table (or it is only for Compute Cluster).
